# How should a forced Hyacinth bulb be cared for after flowering?

Tags: indoors, pots, hyacinth

I bought a hyacinth at the grocery store in a water-only pot with the bulb suspended over the water.

The flowers have now died, and the roots have started to break off of the bulb, although there are a few new roots coming out.

I noticed [this question about hyacinths](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9013/what-should-i-do-to-encourage-my-hyacinth-to-flower-again), but it wasn't clear they were talking about this setup. Since I live in an apartment, I'd rather keep the bulb in a pot if possible.

What is the best way forward for this plant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I don't know that it would be worth going forward with the bulb if you are only interested in keeping it in a pot. Its next step will be to slowly die back and then go dormant until next spring. In a garden bed situation, you would have it nestled in amongst other plants which will cover the dying foliage for the next month or month and a half, because it is going to look very raggedy now that it is done blooming. Then you would not see it at all until it reemerged next spring.

If you have it in a pot by itself, you'll have to accept the fact that it is going to look awful for awhile and then the pot will be empty for most of the year until it emerges again. If that is ok with you, go for it. If not, find a spot to bury it outside or toss it.